# cummulative distinct count

Tags: sql, hive, teradata

I'm having trouble getting a cumulative distinct count so let's just assume the below dataset.

```
   DATE       RID  
   1/1/18      1
   1/1/18      2
   1/1/18      3
   1/1/18      3
```

So if we run this query

```
 SELECT DATE, COUNT(DISTINCT RID) FROM TABLE;
```

we would expect it to return 3, however let's assume that the data for the next day is as follows.

```
 DATE    RID
 1/2/18  1
 1/2/18  6
 1/2/18  9
```

How would you write a query to get the following results where the data for 1/1/18 is considered when returning the distinct for 1/2/18.

So it would be the following results.

```
  Date      Count(*)
  1/1/18      3
  1/2/18      5              <- 1/1/18 distinct plus + 1/2 distinct.
```

Hope that makes sense, keep in mind this is a very large dataset if that changes things.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a cumulative count of the earliest date for each `rid`:

```
select mindate, count(*), sum(count(*)) over (order by mindate)
from (select rid, min(date) as mindate
      from t
      group by rid
     ) t
group by mindate
order by mindate;
```

Note:  This will be missing dates that is not a mindate for some `rid`.   Here is one way to get all the dates, if that is an issue:

```
select mindate, count(rid), sum(count(rid)) over (order by mindate)
from ((select rid, min(date) as mindate
       from t
       group by rid
      )
      union all
      (select distinct NULL, date
       from t
      )
     ) rd
group by mindate
order by mindate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query can give required cumulative distinct count.

`--Step 3:
SELECT dt,
      cum_distinct_cnt
FROM (
    --Step 2:
     SELECT rid,
            dt,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN rid END) OVER (ORDER BY dt ROWS BETWEEN Unbounded PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) cum_distinct_cnt
     FROM (
        --Step 1:
           SELECT rid,
                  dt,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rid ORDER BY dt) row_num
           FROM table) innerTab1
     ) innerTab2 
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dt ORDER BY cum_distinct_cnt DESC) = 1`

Since your dataset is very large, you can break the below query on steps as explained in query and create work tables to populate innerTab1/ innerTab2 to get final output